# nodejs child_process spawn and exec doesn't kill process on process.kill(pid)

Tags: node.js, batch-file, child-process, spawn, execfile

I am working in nodejs. I'm trying to run `.cmd` file using child_process spawn and exec. But none seems to work. Spawn successfully run the `.cmd` file when I run this script `spawn('cmd', ['/c', 'start start_wMBusServices_CLI.cmd'])`.

[image]

but on killing the process using `process.kill(pid)` it generates following error.

[image]

`spawn.kill()` doesn't kill process at all.

I did some digging and I found that the process (pid = 16580) is missing in task manager.

[image]

And child_process.exec just create pid and doesn't run `.cmd` at all.

***Now, what I want is, to kill the process when I click that stop button.***

***I need a simple script to kill this process.***

Here's my whole code

```
let exec = null;
let pId = null;

function startStop() {
  try {
    if (!pId) {
      exec = spawn('cmd', ['/c', "start start_wMBusServices_CLI.cmd"])
      
      // <-- execFile didn't work -->
      -------------------------------

      // exec = execFile(executablePath, { encoding: 'utf-8' }, function (err, stdOut, stdErr) {
      //   console.error(err);
      //   console.error(stdErr);
      // })
      pId = exec.pid
      console.log(pId);
      // if(exec.killed)
      //   pId = null

    }
    else if (pId) {
      // didn't work
      --------------
      // exec.kill()

      // generates error shown before
      -------------------------------
      process.kill(pId)
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  console.log(process);
}
```

Comment: You may try to exit from the process itself, like `if(pid){ exec.exit(0)}`

Comment: i tried and it shows ```renderer.js:81 TypeError: exec.exit is not a function```

Comment: Yes `exec` is indefined in the `else if()` condition. It was just an idea but it won't work here... If the process is missing in the 'task manager' it s mean there is no process... Or the process started and already closed. That s maybee why it generate an err when you try to kill it (as there is no process) ??

Comment: @Jerome thanks for the help but i resolved the issue using batch script.

Comment: @ZeeshanMalik can you please share the solution to the problem? I am also stuck with the same problem.